# Rails form in show page for nested attirbutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the models `Project` and `ProjectLine`.

On `projects/show` I have:

```
<%= @project.name %>

<% @project_lines.each do |project_line| %>

  <%= project_line.description %>

  <%= semantic_form_for project_line do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :status, :value=>4 %>
    <%= f.submit 'COMPLETE', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I am trying to do is, on project show page, to show a project and its project lines, and have a button to change a `project_line`'s status to 'complete'.

project.rb

```
has_many :project_lines
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_lines, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

project_line.rb

```
belongs_to :project
```

In projects_controller:

```
def show
  @project = Project.includes(:user).find_by_id(params[:id])
  @project_line = ProjectLine.includes(:user).find_by_id(params[:id])
  @project_lines = @project.project_lines
end
```

But it returns:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `project_line_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8235644f60>:0x0055eb72a0d4b8>
Did you mean?  project_path
               projects_path):
    109:               </div>
    110: 
    111:               <div class="col-sm-2">
    112:                 <%= semantic_form_for project_line do |f| %>
    113:                     <%= f.hidden_field :status, :value=>4 %>
    114:                   <%= f.submit 'COMPLETE', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' %>
    115:                 <% end %>

app/views/projects/show.html.erb:112:in `block in _app_views_projects_show_html_erb___4141078949623736805_47234864376780'
app/views/projects/show.html.erb:93:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb___4141078949623736805_47234864376780'
^[[Started POST "/__web_console/repl_sessions/440752809903b2f394f0a107e957670f/trace" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-29 20:55:44 +0800
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Show some stack trace.

Comment: can you please also show associations between these models

Comment: i have added the 2 models to show associations

Comment: You should be submitting the form to project path not project line path so it should be `semantic_form_for @project`. Make sure you are using `sematic_fields_for @project_lines` which wraps all the nested fields. Also create a route for projects if not already created.

Comment: if i do that, if for instance i have 3 project lines for the project, it creates 3 buttons submit for each project line. it loops project lines again inside each project line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way, basically using link instead of form.

routes

```
resources :projects do
  resources :project_lines do
    post 'accepted', :on => :member
  end
end
```

project_lines_controller

```
  def accepted
  @project_line = ProjectLine.find_by_id(params[:id])
      @project_line.update(status: "4")
      @project_line.save!
      redirect_to project_lines_path
      flash[:notice] = "MARKED AS ACCEPTED"
end
```

projects/show

```
  <%= link_to "Accept", accepted_project_project_line_path(project_line.project, project_line), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error is saying is that you don't have a route that corresponds to `project_line_path` - which would usually correspond to the `update` action in a `project_lines` controller.

This is a Rails default, with conventions in place to submit a form to the `create` action for non-persisted instances, `update` for persisted.

Therefore, your problem is either:

- you're missing the controller and action to process the form
- you want your form to submit to somewhere other than its convention

To resolve the first of these, create a `product_lines` controller containing an `update` action handling the form as desired, along with a route for this (i.e. `resources :product_lines, only: :update`, perhaps nested within the products routes).

For the latter, you can provide a `url` argument to the form helper, telling it where to submit to, i.e. `<%= semantic_form_for project_line, url: your_custom_path do %>...`.

Finally, if you want to make use of the Formtastic's nested form functionality, you would need something like the following:

```
<%= @project.name %>

<%= semantic_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <% @project_lines.each do |project_line| %>

    <%= project_line.description %>

    <%= f.semantic_fields_for project_line do |project_line_form| %>
      <%= project_line_form.checkbox :status, value: 4, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Note this uses checkboxes for the nested product lines, which would be submitted with the project form. I'm not sure this is the approach you're after so would suggest one of the first approaches, but thought I'd pop it in as you've mentioned using a nested form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With your answer I'm getting closer. But that way it shows only one button submit (for <%= semantic_form_for @project do |f| %>) while it should show one for each project_line.

Comment: And I don't think i can use value: 4 with checkboxes, I'd need to pass a collection.